# Как выводить числа которые можно делить? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Если мы хотим создать 2 случайных числа так, чтобы можно  было  первое число поделить на второе (простое математическое деление). Но так, чтобы без остатка! Как генерировать эти 2 числа?

Вот что я пробовал, но у меня остается остаток при делении.

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*90 + 1);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1);
var result = a / b;
alert(result);
```

Comment: Генерируйте множители, а не делитель и делимое.

Comment: Самое простое так, псевдокод: a = random(); b = random(); a = a*b;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = Math.floor(Math.random()*9 + 1);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1);
var a = result * b;
alert(result);
```

Comment: Все что вы сделали это переделали в умножение, вы читали мой вопрос? Мне нужно деление без остатка...

Comment: @arthru мы читали Ваш вопрос: "создать 2 рандомных чис..." А Вы читали ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Первое генерить рандомно, затем генерить рандомно небольшой множитель. Второе равно произведению первого на множитель. И не нужно никаких переборов

Answer (score 0):

Проверка на то, что число a делится на число b без остатка:

```
if (!(a % b)){...}
```

Соответственно, можете в цикле делать генерацию. Или выбрать одно число, умножить его на другое и получить требующиеся числа.

Comment: Хм, интересно. А как сделать что бы если не может делиться, тогда попробовать сгенерировать другое число, и так пока не найдет подходящее?

Comment: @arthru "можете в цикле делать генерацию.", написал же.

Comment: Я понял что нужно что то вроде while (!(a % b)) { Можете помочь с кодом?

Comment: Только while (a%b), а так вы уже сами практически весь код написали.

Comment: Ну а что внутри while написать лучше всего? Можете помочь с этим?

Comment: @arthru а в чём проблема то? b = Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); внутри цикла.